# Using VBA to run Analysis Toolpack Random Number Generator

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to set up several worksheets for analysis, and thought I'd quickly write a macro to automate the process.

I ran a macro recorder and used the Data Analysis random number generator.  I thought I'd be able to change some substitute some numbers in for the ranges and be done.  It doesn't seem to work like that, and I'm wondering what I'm missing.  I tried to find a page that would list the parameters of the function, but haven't been able to do so.

```
Sub Stuff()
'
' Stuff Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
Dim highFloor As Integer
highFloor = Range("F2").Value

Dim highCeiling As Integer
highCeiling = Range("G2").Value

Dim lowFloor As Integer
lowFloor = Range("H2").Value

Dim lowCeiling As Integer
lowCeiling = Range("I2").Value

Dim randomSeed As Integer
randomSeed = Range("P2").Value

    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Random", ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4"), 1, 1000 _
        , 1, ActiveSheet.Range("$P$2"), highFloor, highCeiling

     Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Random", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$4"), 1, 1000 _
        , 1, ActiveSheet.Range("$P$2"), lowFloor, lowCeiling

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you passing `ActiveSheet.Range("$P$2")` as the 5th parameter? As far as I can tell thats for the `Random Seed` value.

Comment: You're totally right.  I've edited that to what it should be.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Everything here works as I would expect.  What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: You know when you've stared at a spreadsheet for too long?  I was declaring lowFloor as highFloor and lowCeiling as lowCeiling (I forgot to update after cutting and pasting).  I've updated and it works as expected.  I've left the random seed hardcoded, but it could be called as randomSeed too.